# phaser - how to find mobile device notch size

Tags: phaser-framework, phaserjs

My game is running fullscreen on mobile devices but I need to keep some top safe space to avoid notch space and statusbar.

Found this scale examples but it doesn't handle notch/statusbar spaces.

```
scale: {
  mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
  autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH
},
```

Is there any way to do this?

In IONIC it has CSS variable called `safe-area-inset-top`, but I don't know how to bring it's value to Phaser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no phone with a notch to test this, I assume you could set the styles ***environment variables*** on a element like `body`

*(I added a default padding of `10px` you could set it to any other value)*

```css
.body-class {
    padding-top: max(env(safe-area-inset-top), 10px);
    padding-bottom: max(env(safe-area-inset-bottom), 10px);
    padding-left: max(env(safe-area-inset-left), 10px);
    padding-right: max(env(safe-area-inset-right), 10px);
}
```

And than you could get the dimensions, with `getComputedStyle` ([link to the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)):

```js
...
let widthOffSet = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('width'); 
let heighthOffSet = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('height'); 
...

new Phaser.Game({ width, height, ... });
```

Comment: worked like a charm and I made an easier solution without need of a custom div: `parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--ion-safe-area-top').replace('px', '')) || 0;`